# How to call a function from child to parent using EventEmitter Ouput and subscribe

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-datatable

I need to refresh a table from the modalComponent using an event.

In child component

```
 @Output() callrefresh = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

when add data

```
this.callrefresh .emit('I want to call a function');
```

In parent component i want activate this function

```
    refreshTable(){ 
    this.tableRefresh();
    }
```

Any help plz? an example would be nice

In the parent component i have a table and in the child the modal. When i save a data row in child component i want active the refresh function in parent component.

For example in child component

```
this.service.save(this.car).subscribe(
        (result) => {
          this.closeModal();
          this.callrefresh .emit('I want to call a function');
        },
```

In parent component

```
 refreshTable(){ 
this.tableRefresh();
}


     tableRefresh(      
    page?: Page
  ): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.service
        .findAlldata(
          this.sort.dir,
          this.page.pageNumber,
          this.page.size,
          this.sort.prop
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: (data: any) => {
           all paged data logic
            );              
          },
          error: (error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
          complete: () => {
            console.log('complete');
          },
        })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add more details, what's your intent, from which component you want to access what and put more code of both the components you wish to interact. Or a stackblitz would also be fine.

Comment: Please post the relevant template as well. Make sure your question includes a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the event triggered by your output. When you emit, refreshTable() gets called

```
<child (callrefresh)="refreshTable()"></child>
```

Comment: don't work, could you give me a complete example plz

Comment: This is exactly how an Output works, so If it doesnt, its because your refreshTable doesnt work.

Comment: with subscribe , child hashtag  breaks the table view

Comment: Child doesnt exist since its just an example, you need to use your actual component selector

Comment: yes , i used my component selector but don't work